# How should one debug a SIGABRT in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sigabrt, lldb

The iOS simulator is issuing a SIGABRT signal attributed to main.m.

I am confused since I did not change main.m. Backtracing the debugger always returns the main function, which is not useful to me.

How does one go about debugging a SIGABRT signal in iOS? I wish XCode could let me know which line I wrote caused the signal to fire.

Here is what the console issues after terminating my program.

```
Couldn't register com.inimicalme.me.iosapp43 with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.
```

I'm not quite sure though what this means or if it is directly related to the issuing of the SIGABRT.

Comment: I updated my question to include the console message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in the console usually means you need to restart your device, restart Xcode or restart your Mac. Or some combination of those.

Although, that's not usually associated with a SIGABRT, but give it a try.

Comment: Thank you, restarting XCode did not work, but restarting my Mac Air did. I wonder why.

Comment: I think we all wonder why ... happens more often than I'd like

Answer (score 0):

The hang usually happens between two pieces - xcode and your device. If the device is a simulator, a restart will be needed. If not...

1. unplug your device
2. reset it
3. close xcode
4. reopen xcode
5. start again!

Good luck in the future.